# Type number is not assignable to type string

Tags: javascript

Im making an Incremental game and came across an error......... Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' on all the document.getElement....

```
var vegetas = 0;
var gohan = 0;

function vegetaClick(number) {
    vegetas = vegetas + number;
    document.getElementById("Textout").innerHTML = vegetas;
};

function buyGohan() {
    var gohanCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,gohan));     
    if(vegetas >= gohanCost){                                   
        gohan = gohan + 1;                                   
        vegetas = vegetas - gohanCost;                         
        document.getElementById("gohan").innerHTML = gohan;  
        document.getElementById('vegetas').innerHTML = vegetas;  
        document.getElementById("gohan").style.display= "block";
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,gohan));       
    document.getElementById('gohanCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  
};
```

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt - innerHTML is returning a string, but `vegetas` and `gohan` are both ints.

Comment: which browser are you test on? it's ok to assign a number to innerHTML in chrome at least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force `nextCost` to be coerced into a string value:

```
document.getElementById('gohanCost').innerHTML = "" + nextCost;
```

or

```
// Note, no new
document.getElementById('gohanCost').innerHTML = String(nextCost);
```

Comment: Assigning a numeric value to `innerHTML` works fine for me.